# Убрать ноль в конце списка

Tags: python, numpy

Есть такой код, (ввод и вывод измененной матрицы) я не могу преобразовать ее (reshape) из за того что в конце вставляется 0, но если его убрать из метода append, то тогда возникает ошибка, что делать?

```
import numpy as np
n, m = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
a = [[int(j) for j in input().split()] for i in range(n*m)]
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        mas = np.append(a, 0)
mas.reshape(2, 2)
print(mas)
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Что делать?" --  учить Python. И пытаться сначала понять, что вы хотите сделать, а потом делать. Смотрим ваш код. Можно узнать, что вообще вы делаете??
И почему именно так?

Сначала создаете *список* "а".  Чудесно.
Затем зачем-то append-ом  переносим поэлементно элементы из а в массив numpy(!!!!)???
Почему напрямую не писать в numpy-массив? Например, вот так:

```
import numpy as np
n, m = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
mas = np.array([[int(j) for j in input().split()] for i in range(n*m)]).reshape(2, 2)
print(mas)
```

Результат работы:

```
2 2
1
2
3
4

[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
```

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться, к чему все эти наезды? Почему нельзя обойтись без них?

Comment: Конечно, спасибо за ответ, но все таки наезды лишние